# For custom WebDriver while i try to using EventFiringDecorator getting ClasscastException

Tags: java, spring-boot, selenium-webdriver

I have created a Custom webdriver class for webdriver, in selenium 3 i have used eventFiringWebdriver to extent my customdrvier class and i'll pass my customerwebdriver in constructor which was working fine,
now i'm trying to migrate my framework from selenium 3 to 4 and i have updated my code as mentioned below

```
class MyCustomeDriver extends EventFiringDecorator{

 public MyCustomeDriver(Environment env) throws MalformedURLException {
        super.decorate(getDriver(env));  <--- this getDriver method will return webDriver
    }
```

for this above code snippet I'm not getting any compile time error where as, when i try to call my driver instance its not returning webdriver instance instead its returning MyCustomeDriver instance, so to get the webdriver I tried to cast it but i'm getting ClassCastException while executing it please help me to fix it

I'm using java 17 and selenium 4.16.1
https://github.com/appium/java-client/issues/1694

#### How can we reproduce the issue?

```bash
similar to below issue 
https://github.com/appium/java-client/issues/1694
```

#### Relevant log output

```bash
getting ClassCastException
```

#### Operating System

Windows 10

#### Selenium version

4.16.1

#### What are the browser(s) and version(s) where you see this issue?

chrome 115

#### What are the browser driver(s) and version(s) where you see this issue?

Webdriver manager

#### Are you using Selenium Grid?

_No

for this above code snippet I'm not getting any compile time error where as, when i try to call my driver instance its not returning webdriver instance instead its returning MyCustomeDriver instance, so to get the webdriver I tried to cast it but i'm getting ClassCastException while executing it please help me to fix it

I'm using java 17 and selenium 4.16.1
https://github.com/appium/java-client/issues/1694